# Can I use a USA Led Bulb in Europe?

Tags: led, energy, adapter

I am a software engineer working with an IOT company in the states, Right now I am located in Europe for a month and a half, and have some hardware (light bulbs) that I need to use to finish some stuff faster.

I have an adapter that goes from the bulb socket to the US based plug, I am thinking about buying an adapter from the us plug to the eu one its that fine? or I need something else?

this are the bulbs I am using https://www.bulbspro.com/tcp-cas11lc.html

Sorry for not giving more info, I am new working on this company mostly with software and don't have a lot of knowledge in electronics.

Comment: Questions about the usage of consumer products are generally off-topic here.  Only with relevant technical specifications stated *in the body of the question itself* and the statement of a clear, specific, engineering question could this possibly remain.  If these are test devices for your IoT gadget, you should probably consult with your co-workers responsible for the electrical aspects.  If these are just lights to use in your temporary home, the question really does not belong here.

Comment: @ChrisStratton got you, posted it here because didn't knew where to start asking questions and my coworkers aren't still online, will try to find the technical specifications.

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov updated with a description, this means is only 120V ? or that can be used on the 240 volts one? what other alternative I have here there is a voltage adapter?

Comment: USA only.  It would probably light up if you used a 240 to 120 VAC transformer.  Damifino if the control signals would pass through the transformer.  Probably not, though.

Answer (score 3):

If the bulbs are rated for use on 120 VAC only, then they will almost certainly be destroyed if you attempt to use them on the common European 240 Volts.

If they are rated for operation on both 120 and 240 volts (or as many computer and phone chargers, 90 - 250 volts) then they will be OK on 240 volts.

Comment: there is also the question of power line frequency ..... the circuit inside the bulb may be tuned to 60Hz, and may produce unexpected results when powered from 50Hz mains